# Getting a timeout error when trying to reach Yahoo mail through all apps. That's the only site with an issue. Samsung s20 fe 5g 1ui4.0

Tags: yahoo-mail, samsung-galaxy-s-20

Received a replacement s20fe last week and haven't been able to reach Yahoo mail since. It times out or returns a 'This page isn't working' message. Can't even get through with the Yahoo mail app.

No problems reaching any other site or service. The only problem is getting to Yahoo, with any app.

Answer (score 0):

AT&T sent an OTA that resolved the issue.